# Making a dataframe with binary data based on conditions in another

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, binary-data

I have a large data frame which I want to filter and make a binary data frame for based on several conditions.

This is the original data frame:

```
a1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep("ID_1",3),rep("ID_2",3)),
  gene = c("A", "D", "X","D","D","A"),
  C = c("Q", "R", "S","S","R","Q"),
  D = c(8, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4),
  E = sample(c("silent","non-silent"),6,replace=T)
)
```

eg:

```
    ID  gene    C   D   E
1   ID_1    A   Q   8   non-silent
2   ID_1    D   R   3   silent
3   ID_1    X   S   3   silent
4   ID_2    D   S   4   non-silent
5   ID_2    D   R   5   silent
6   ID_2    A   Q   4   non-silent
```

I now have made an empty data frame with the IDs as columns and genes as rows as such:

```
dt=as.data.frame(matrix(NA, length(c(levels(a1$gene))), length(c(levels(a1$ID)))+1))
colnames(dt)[1] <- "gene"
dt[,"gene"]=c(levels(a1$gene))
colnames(dt)[-1]=levels(a1$ID)

    gene    ID_1    ID_2
1   A   NA  NA
2   D   NA  NA
3   X   NA  NA
```

Now I would want to put a 1 for genes that are present for each ID and 0 for those that are not present. I would later also want to include other conditions. For example only put a 1 for non-silent in the E column. Is there an R base way to do this or with a package such as data.table or ddply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(a1, gene ~ ID)
#   gene ID_1 ID_2
# 1    A    1    1
# 2    D    1    2
# 3    X    1    0
```

or

```
dcast(a1, gene ~ ID, fun.aggregate = function(x) (length(x) > 0L) * 1L)
#   gene ID_1 ID_2
# 1    A    1    1
# 2    D    1    1
# 3    X    1    0
```

It's also available for data tables.

Comment: This is a nice solution, it works perfectly for the example. But I get some strange results for the original data. An error message: Using freq as value column: use value.var to override. And not all IDs are present in the binarytable.

Comment: I don't know about your real data, but to get rid of the warning (?) message just specify `value.var = "ID"` explicitly.

Comment: Solved it, thank you! But what if I want to include other columns, to for example only have non-silent in the E column?

Comment: You could change the formula from `gene ~ ID` to `gene + E ~ ID`.

Comment: if OP's data is a `data.table`, use `dcast.data.table` instead of `dcast` to get the best of both worlds

Answer (score 1):

To see if a gene is present for each ID:

```
dt$ID_1 <- dt$gene %in% a1[a1$ID == "ID_1", ]$gene
dt$ID_2 <- dt$gene %in% a1[a1$ID == "ID_2", ]$gene
```

so `dt$ID_1 & dt$ID_2` will give you those that are present in both.

If you have many IDs and you want to iterate over them, you can use e.g. `lapply` and if you want to apply it to other columns you just need to replace this string by a variable (and turn it into a function).